# Google Adwords API Exception: More than one SoapHeader while invoking public abstract SimpleMutateJob

Tags: java, adsense, google-ads-api

I am using Google Adwords API v201502 via the Java client they provide.

I got this error when making mutate call to google.

I know the [AdwordsSession is not thread](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/wiki/Thread-Safety#threadsafety-in-the-java-library) safe but I have one adwords session object per thread. In my case, every thread has its own AdwordsSession object but two AdwordsSessions might have the same clientCustomerId.

I tried to modify multiple ad groups in the same campaign in one account at the same time and I got the following error.

My goal is to modify the CPC bid for multiple adgroups in parallel (1 CPC change per adgroup).

How do I achieve parallisation with AdwordsSession?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>More than one SoapHeader while invoking public abstract com.google.ads.api.services.job.mutate.v201502.jaxbgen.SimpleMutateJob com.google.ads.api.services.job.mutate.v201502.jaxbgen.MutateJobServiceInterface.mutate(java.util.List,com.google.ads.api.services.job.mutate.v201502.jaxbgen.BulkMutateJobPolicy) throws com.google.ads.api.services.job.mutate.v201502.jaxbgen.ApiException_Exception with params </faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had also posted this question in [Adwords API Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adwords-api/paralleisation/adwords-api/t_zdfGj7UyM/K-yYupS5TaAJ) and got the answer. i.e. ***MutateJobServiceInterface*** is also not thread-safe. Hence, I created one Adwords Session object and one ***MutateJobServiceInterface*** object for one thread and I am now able to parallelise multiple mutate API calls to Google Adwords.